# Hive - Create map columns type by aggregating values across groups

Tags: sql, hadoop, types, hive, collect

I have a table that looks like this:

```
|customer|category|room|date|
-----------------------------
|1       |   A    | aa | d1 |
|1       |   A    | bb | d2 |
|1       |   B    | cc | d3 |
|1       |   C    | aa | d1 |
|1       |   C    | bb | d2 |
|2       |   A    | aa | d3 |
|2       |   A    | bb | d4 |
|2       |   C    | bb | d4 |
|2       |   C    | ee | d5 |
|3       |   D    | ee | d6 |
```

I want to create two maps out of the table:

**1st**. *map_customer_room_date*: will *group by* customer and **collect** all different rooms (**key**) and with date (**value**).

I'm using the `collect()` [*UDF Brickhouse*](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) function.

*this can be archived with something similar as:*

```
select customer, collect(room,date) as map_customer_room_date
from table
group by customer
```

**2nd.** *map_category_room_date* A bit more complicated, consists also of the same map type `collect(room, date)` and it will contain as keys, all the rooms across ALL categories where for customer X is categories.
This means that for *customer1* it will take room `ee` even though it belongs to *customer2*. This is because customer1 has category `C` and this category is also present in customer 2.

The **final table** is grouped by customer and will look like:

```
|customer| map_customer_room_date  |     map_category_room_date    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1    |{aa: d1, bb: d2, cc: d3} |{aa: d1, bb: d2, cc: d3,ee: d6}|
|   2    |{aa: d3, bb: d4, ee: d6} |{aa: d3, bb: d4, ee: d6}       |
|   3    |{ee: d6}                 |{ee: d6}                       |
```

I am having issues building the second map and presenting the final table as described.
Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a series of self-joins to find other rooms in the same category before combining the results into 2 maps.

### Code

```
CREATE TABLE `table` AS
SELECT 1 AS customer, 'A' AS category, 'aa' AS room, 'd1' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS customer, 'A' AS category, 'bb' AS room, 'd2' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS customer, 'B' AS category, 'cc' AS room, 'd3' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS customer, 'C' AS category, 'aa' AS room, 'd1' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS customer, 'C' AS category, 'bb' AS room, 'd2' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS customer, 'A' AS category, 'aa' AS room, 'd3' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS customer, 'A' AS category, 'bb' AS room, 'd4' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS customer, 'C' AS category, 'bb' AS room, 'd4' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS customer, 'C' AS category, 'ee' AS room, 'd5' AS `date` UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS customer, 'D' AS category, 'ee' AS room, 'd6' AS `date`
;


SELECT
    customer_rooms.customer,
    collect(customer_rooms.room, customer_rooms.date) AS map_customer_room_date,
    collect(
        COALESCE(customer_category_rooms.room, category_rooms.room),
        COALESCE(customer_category_rooms.date, category_rooms.date)) AS map_category_room_date
FROM `table` AS customer_rooms
JOIN `table` AS category_rooms ON customer_rooms.category = category_rooms.category
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` AS customer_category_rooms ON customer_rooms.customer = customer_category_rooms.customer
AND category_rooms.category = customer_category_rooms.category
AND category_rooms.room = customer_category_rooms.room
WHERE (
    customer_rooms.customer = customer_category_rooms.customer AND
    customer_rooms.category = customer_category_rooms.category AND
    customer_rooms.room = customer_category_rooms.room AND
    customer_rooms.date = customer_category_rooms.date
)
OR (
    customer_category_rooms.customer IS NULL AND
    customer_category_rooms.category IS NULL AND
    customer_category_rooms.room IS NULL AND
    customer_category_rooms.date IS NULL
)
GROUP BY
    customer_rooms.customer
;
```

### Result Set

```
1   {"aa":"d1","bb":"d2","cc":"d3"} {"aa":"d1","bb":"d2","cc":"d3","ee":"d5"}
2   {"aa":"d3","bb":"d4","ee":"d5"} {"aa":"d3","bb":"d4","ee":"d5"}
3   {"ee":"d6"} {"ee":"d6"}
```

### Explanation

```
FROM `table` AS customer_rooms
```

First, results are drawn from the initial `table`.  We name this relation `customer_rooms`.  As you already noted in the question, this much is sufficient to build `map_customer_room_date`.

```
JOIN `table` AS category_rooms ON customer_rooms.category = category_rooms.category
```

The first self-join identifies all rooms that have the same categories as the rooms explicitly mentioned in the `customer_rooms` rows.  We name this relation `category_rooms`.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` AS customer_category_rooms ON customer_rooms.customer = customer_category_rooms.customer
AND category_rooms.category = customer_category_rooms.category
AND category_rooms.room = customer_category_rooms.room
```

The second self-join takes the rooms that we identified in `category_rooms` and attempts to find if this room is already held by the customer identified in `customer_rooms`.  We name this relation `customer_category_rooms`.  This is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because we want to preserve all rows from the prior joins.  The outcome will either be 1) the values from `customer_rooms` and `customer_category_rooms` are identical, because the customer already holds this room, or 2) the values from `customer_category_rooms` will be all `NULL`, because the customer doesn't hold this room, but it's a room in one of the same categories.  This distinction will become important so that we can preserve the `date` of the customer if they already hold the room.

Next, we need to filter.

```
WHERE (
    customer_rooms.customer = customer_category_rooms.customer AND
    customer_rooms.category = customer_category_rooms.category AND
    customer_rooms.room = customer_category_rooms.room AND
    customer_rooms.date = customer_category_rooms.date
)
```

This includes the rooms that are explicitly held by the customer in the original `table`.

```
OR (
    customer_category_rooms.customer IS NULL AND
    customer_category_rooms.category IS NULL AND
    customer_category_rooms.room IS NULL AND
    customer_category_rooms.date IS NULL
)
```

This includes the rooms that are not held by the customer but belong in the same categories as rooms held by the customer.

```
    collect(customer_rooms.room, customer_rooms.date) AS map_customer_room_date,
```

`map_customer_room_date` can be built by collecting the original data from the table, which we had aliased as `customer_rooms`.

```
    collect(
        COALESCE(customer_category_rooms.room, category_rooms.room),
        COALESCE(customer_category_rooms.date, category_rooms.date)) AS map_category_room_date
```

Building `map_category_room_date` is more complex.  If the customer holds the room explicitly, then we want to preserve that `date`.  However, if the customer does not hold the room explicitly, then we want to be able to use the `room` and `date` from another row that has an overlapping category.  To accomplish that, we use the Hive [COALESCE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions) function to choose the first value that is not `NULL`.  If the customer already holds the room (as present in non-`NULL` values in `customer_category_rooms`), then we'll use that.  If not, then we'll use values from `category_rooms` instead.

Note that there can still be some ambiguity if the same category/room combination can map to multiple `date` values.  If that is significant, then you might need to put more work into this to choose the right `date` based on some business rule (e.g. use the soonest `date`) or map to multiple `date` values instead of a single value.  This should give you a good starting point though if there are additional requirements like that.